# List Items Vertical Align no working for IE 7 8 or 9

Tags: internet-explorer, alignment, html-lists, vertical-alignment, css

I did some research and tried some methods but nothing seems to work for IE.

I have a Vertical List Style Menu. Example would be

```
<ul class="menuleft">
<li><a href="index.php" >Home</a></li>
<li><a href="maritime-marinas.php" >Maritime Marinas</a></li>
</ul>
```

My CSS is

```
ul.menuleft {list-style-type: none; margin:0; padding:0;}
.menuleft li {
    width:248px;
    height:47px;
    background-image:url(images/left-menu-bg-off.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
   line-height:47px;
    text-align: left;
    text-indent: 60px;

   }

.menuleft {text-decoration: none; font-family:Arial Narrow, Arial; color:#FFFFFF; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #052f5b; font-size:18px;}
.menuleft a:link {text-decoration: none; font-family:Arial Narrow, Arial; color:#FFFFFF; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #052f5b; font-size:18px;}
.menuleft a:visited {text-decoration: none; font-family:Arial Narrow, Arial; color:#FFFFFF; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #052f5b; font-size:18px;}
.menuleft a:hover {text-decoration: underline; font-family:Arial Narrow, Arial; color:#FFFFFF; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #052f5b; font-size:18px;}
.menuleft a:active {text-decoration: none; font-family:Arial Narrow, Arial; color:#FFFFFF; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #052f5b; font-size:18px;}
```

The text vertically centers perfect for Firefox, Safari and Chrome. But not IE 7 8 or 9 (also not Opera)

Please help. Thank you